# Compute $\int_{-1+|y|}^{1-|y|} \frac{3}{4} (|x|+|y|) \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus

I'm working with a function $f$ given by
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{4} (|x|+|y|), & |x|+|y|\leq 1 \\
0,                     & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and I need to compute the following integral:
$$
\int_{-1+|y|}^{1-|y|} \frac{3}{4} (|x|+|y|) \, dx
$$
But I'm not able to solve it... Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-1+|y|}^{1-|y|} \frac{3}{4}(|x|+|y|) dx$$
$$=\frac{3}{4} \int_{-1+|y|}^{1-|y|} |x| dx + \frac{3}{4}\int_{-1+|y|}^{1-|y|} |y|dx$$
$$=-\frac{3}{4} \int_{-1+|y|}^{0} x dx+\frac{3}{4} \int_{0}^{1-|y|}xdx + \frac{3}{4}|y| \left( (1-|y|)-(-1+|y|) \right)$$
$$=\frac{3}{4} \frac{1}{2} (-1+|y|)^2 + \frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2}(1-|y|)^2 + \frac{3}{4}|y|(2-2|y|)$$
$$=\frac{3}{4} \left(1-|y|^2 \right)$$

Comment: Please read: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1